# Strange problem with rendered=true/false issues in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I am having a very simple but annoying issue with JSF. I have a datatable (with simple first next etc paging option) , which I want to populate from same page where users do initial selection.

Initial Form

```
<b><h:selectOneRadio id="radio1" layout="pageDirection" style="font-weight: bold" value="#{displayNOC.slection}">       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By NOC" itemValue="N" id="selectItem1" />
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By Title" itemValue="T" id="selectItem2" />
</h:selectOneRadio></td>
<hx:commandExButton type="submit" image="images/btn_search.jpg" action="#{displayNOC.Process_request}" onclick="return validate_ListNoc(this.form)"></hx:commandExButton></b>
```

Once user select a radio button and click "search", I am populating a datatable (which is hidden in the same page with rendered properties false) and a paging button (at this stage I only have NEXT button which is also hidden at the time of form load using rendered property) without any problem .

```
<B>Search Results :<BR><BR>
<h:inputHidden id="text1" value="#{displayNOC.firstRow}" ></h:inputHidden>
navigation Next button start
<hx:commandExButton type="submit" value="Next" action="#{displayNOC.goNext}" rendered="#{displayNOC.render_panel_status}" disabled="#{displayNOC.firstRow + displayNOC.rowPerPage >= displayNOC.totalSize}">
</hx:commandExButton>

<h:dataTable border="1" id="table" value="#{displayNOC.WAMNOC}" rendered="#{displayNOC.render_status}" var="SearchResult" headerClass="row2" rowClasses="row-even,row-odd" cellspacing="6">
 <h:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
  <h:commandLink value="NOC_Number" style="text-align: center">
    </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{SearchResult[0]}" />
         </h:column>
......................
.......................
</h:datatable>
```

My managed bean SCOPE:REQUEST in face-config.xml is as follows (I have all the getter and setter for all the vars)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void Process_request()
 {
  setRender_status(true);
  setRender_panel_status(true);
  WAMNOCSERVICE WNS=new WAMNOCSERVICE();
  List<WAM_NOC> wnoc= WNS.getNOCandOccupation(0,10);
  //get the total size of the records
  setTotalSize(WNS.totalRecordAvaiable());
  setTotalpage(wnoc.size()/10);
  setRowPerPage(10);
  setFirstRow(1);
  setWAMNOC(wnoc);
 }

 //this action is for next button in the table paging
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void goNext()
 {
  setRender_status(true);
  setRender_panel_status(true);
  setRowPerPage(10);
  System.out.println(firstRow);
  firstRow = getFirstRow() + rowPerPage;
  WAMNOCSERVICE WNS=new WAMNOCSERVICE();
  List<WAM_NOC> wnoc= WNS.getNOCandOccupation(firstRow,rowPerPage);
  setWAMNOC(wnoc);
  }
```

My problem is when I click GoNext() button render_status never set to true and I never see any datatable or button any more. Admitting I am new to JSF , this was the last thing I thought will give me such trouble. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the `rendered` attribtue is re-evaluated in the subsequent request. But since it's depending on a request scoped bean which get garbaged by end of response and recreated on a next new request, this condition will turn back to default and so the action won't be invoked when you have this in an `UICommand` component or one of its parents.

In JSF 1.x there are several solutions to go around this:

- Put bean in session scope. Easiest, but not good for user experience whenever the enduser opens the same page in multiple tabs/browsers on the same session.
- Use `<h:inputHidden>` with a binding. Nasty, more detail can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925118/values-lost-after-validation-error-in-jsf/1925318#1925318).
- Use Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>` to retain the bean in the next request. Clean and nice, but requires additional component library.

  ```
  <t:saveState value="#{displayNOC}" />
  ```

The JSF 2.0 solution would be to just put the bean in the view scope.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have been following your post/site and learned JSF basically from your posted articles. I have one follow-up question, what would be the best way to handle this in JSF 1.1 version. I just checked my Websphere plug-ins and it is JSF 1.1 . Once again thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Oh, you originally tagged the question as JSF 2.0, so I assumed it JSF 2.0. Unfortunately, it's going to be hacky on JSF 1.x... I updated the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it helped in solving the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq